# IDE code completion in Angular custom library generated by ng-packagr

Tags: javascript, angular, phpstorm, webstorm

I have a library generated in Angular for use in other projects. I generated it with ng-packagr.

When I use a component from that library to a consumer project, it does not show all the IDE goodies like code completion etc.

For e.g. a component `app-my-input` has an Input() attribute `title`, now the usage would be:

```
<app-my-input [title]="'my title here'"></app-my-input>
```

Now when I usually use a third party component like this in an IDE like WebStorm/PhpStorm, and I just type `inp` after `<app-my-input`, I get a suggestion `[input]` automatically, but for my library I am not getting this suggestion.

My `public_api.ts` file has all the component's .ts files and module's .ts files exported. Is there something else I need to export to get the code completion working?

Comment: How did you add your library to your project? Where is it located? If you go to `Project Settings > Modules`, can you see it as Content Root (or within an already defined one)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include either your component sources (`.ts` files with definitions of your classes) or the `*.metadata.json` (https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/getting-your-angular-2-library-ready-for-aot-90d1347bcad) in your published package in order to get your components recognized by the static code analysis; code completion, etc. won't work otherwise